# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

Tengo un problema con mi Middleware.

```
    class Mantenimiento
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)

    {
        
        $config = Configuraciones::findOrFail(0);
        if ($config->mantenimiento == null) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('estado');
        }

    }
}
```

El problema es que al enviarme a la ruta me da el error: **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

localhost te redireccionó demasiadas veces

```
Route::get('estado', 'SistemaController@showconfig' )->name('estado');
```

Kernel:

```
 protected $middleware = [
      
        \App\Http\Middleware\Mantenimiento::class,
      
    ];
```

La ruta al que redirecciono no requiere estar loggeado.

Comment: Posiblemente estás en un bucle de redirecciones. Esto se puede producir si aplicaste el middleware a rutas no deseadas o lo registraste de forma global para todas tus rutas. Puedes dejar tus rutas y la forma en que registraste el middleware?

Comment: Si, ya actualice el post con las rutas

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás aplicando el middleware de forma global. Entonces, como la condición no se cumple y el middleware también se aplica en la ruta de redirección se crea un bucle de redirecciones.

Para solucionar el problema lo primero es no aplicar el middleware a toda la aplicación y registrarlo manualmente, para ello utiliza el array `$routeMiddleware` en vez del array `$middleware`.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'nombre_del_middleware' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\Mantenimiento::class,
];
```

Al registrarlo en dicho array el middleware solo aplicará en las rutas que lo agregues explícitamente.

Ahora a las rutas que quieres proteger con tutus otras rutas puedes agregar tu middleware que para este efecto hemos llamado *nombre_del_middleware*.

```
Route::get('otra_ruta', 'AlgunController@showconfig' )->middleware('nombre_del_middleware');
```

No apliques el middleware a la ruta de destino de la redirección, ya que se creará el bucle infinito.

Si la cantidad de rutas a donde quieres aplicar un middleware son hartas, puedes agruparlas y agregar el middleware al grupo, para conocer más sobre los middleware simplemente ve a la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#introduction).

**Actualización**

Puedes excluir lógica en un middleware condicionando la ruta actual en el middleware.

Para obtener la ruta actual asegúrate de importar la fachada y llamar a la respectiva función, en este caso devolverá el nombre de la ruta o null si esta no tiene nombre.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
$route = Route::currentRouteName();
```

Hay otras formas de acceder a la ruta actual, para ello revisa la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route).

Luego puedes validar si la ruta actual es la de destino y evitar la redirección.

```
if ($config->mantenimiento == null) {
    return $next($request);
}
$route = Route::currentRouteName();
if($route == "NOMBRE_DE_TU_RUTA"){
    return $next($request);
}
return redirect()->route('estado');
```

Comment: Si pero yo quiero que funcione en toda la aplicación, que el middleware no permita ver ninguna sección, hasta que sea desactivado obviamente

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta